# How do I specify a microcontroller as RAM?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, interface, ram

Recently I've been thinking of creating a basic game console using either SPI or Parallel interfaces (I would also like to know which would be the best and easiest for this situation). Using an ATMEGA-328 (arduino bootloader) as the CPU how would I go about specifying a microcontroller, if that would be the proper IC to use, as the RAM. As well how would I send and store data on the RAM as well as retrieve it?

Comment: the microcontroller has ram on it.  what are you asking?

Comment: A microcontroller is not a kind of RAM,  and a RAM is not a kind of microcontroller. You can not use one for the function of the other.

Comment: He wants to emulate a parallel RAM IC on a ATMega, I Think. Which is a bad Idea. The ATMEGA 328 probably doesn't have the amount of ram, or the speed for random memory access that a console requires. Sure you can run a few basic games on it, but not like a console.

Comment: As a learning experience, I think this isn't a terrible idea.  In terms of learning, however, using an FPGA would be even better.

Comment: This question is unclear. Either you are confused about a lot of the components that goes in to creating a game console, the terminology, or you're trying to solve a very specific problem without giving enough details for us to work with.

Comment: This question make no sense. -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't. A Microcontroller is a poor IC to use as external Random Access Memory. You would have to program it to act as RAM. Which would suck due to limited code and RAM space, and even with assembly or machine code, would be slow to respond compared to dedicated RAM ICs.

You want either serial accessible or parallel accessible RAM IC. The ATMEGA as far as I can tell doesn't have an external RAM peripheral, so any access with it will be code intensive. Both serial and parallel ram have cons and pros. Serial takes longer, but parallel requires more pins. For a beginner, neither is better than the other.